# JSON data not getting into HTML table

Tags: php, html, json, html-table

I am fetching JSON from a PHP response. The JSON data is:

```
{
    "success": "200",
    "data": {
        "id": "amit_0001sin",
        "email": "xyz@email.com",
        "Lastupdate": "",
        "name": "amit singhal"
    }
}
```

The JSON should be displayed in a two-column HTML table, but it is not displayed.

The JavaScript code for fetching the JSON and displaying it is:

```
function loadstats() {
    var search_stat= $('#enq_field').val();

    if(search_stat !=""){
        $.ajax({
            url: "dom.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#enqfield_show").html("");
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    $("#enqfield_show").html("<li>" + value + "</li>");
                    $("#enqfield_show").append("<li>" +key +" : "+ value + "</li>");
                });
                $("#enqfield_show").append( "<br/>");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("ERROR: ");
                for(var key in data) {
                    $('#enqfield_show').append(key);
                    $('#enqfield_show').append('=' + data[key] + '<br />');
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#enqfield_show').append('<h1>something wrong</h1>');
    }
    evt.preventDefault();
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it seems like your json string is not a valid json

Comment: and where is the `evt` getting passed to your `evt.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: my mistake i put wrong json, i have corrected it, but still notworking

Comment: @1976Umar check my updated answer just change your `each` part then it is workng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each(data.data, function (key, value) {
                    $("#enqfield_show").html("<li>" + value + "</li>");
                    $("#enqfield_show").append("<li>" +key +" : "+ value + "</li>");
                });
```